# Generating list of(?) for given number

Tags: python, math

I don't know how to call it:
I want to generate lists for given number. Examples for three numbers:

```
3.
[1,1,1]
[1,2]
4.
[1,1,1,1]
[1,1,2]
[1,3]
[2,2]
5.
[1,1,1,1,1]
[1,1,1,2]
[1,2,2]
[1,1,3]
[1,4]
[2,3]
```

Looks simple, but somehow my brain stuck with doing these in recursion or list/array.

Comment: You need to get all integers that sumed together give the asked number, right?

Comment: is order important for the output?

Comment: But what are the rules? In the example with `5` can you have `[2, 3]`?

Comment: You are looking to get the partition of a given number. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory))

Comment: Yes, partitions. I knewed this and forgot.

Comment: Yes, for 5, also [2,3]. Missed it.